# How to get a Drawable instance in class that extends BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable

I'm new to android and i'm to instantiate a Drawable reference.

If the class extends Activity we could directly use this..

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
```

iv.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);

As my class is an custom Adapter the `getResources` method is not available.

Is there any way around...?

I have already tried this...

```
    imageview.setTag(R.drawable.stack_default);
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Adapter is constructed, pass the activity context to the adapter and save it as a member variable.

Or

If you have the Application Instance then get reference to that and then extract the drawable.

Answer (score 1):

`ImageView` has the `setImageResources(int resId)` method which takes as parameter the id of the resouces you need, si, in this case there is no need to use getResources(). Anyway you could use the context of the `ViewGroup` parent paramter of `getView(..)`

You can retrieve it this way:

```
Context context = parent.getContext();
```

then you can use it to retrive the `Resources`

```
context.getResources()
```

You want to check if (parent != null)

Comment: parent is not guaranteed to be valid all the time.